# Unable to show images in android emulator over 4.0 version?

Tags: android, image, web-services

I am trying to show one image from web service by consuming it.Well its working 
fine.If i test my project with android versions like 2 - 3 versions its working fine.But it is not supporting over 4.0 and above. Why?

How to overcome this issue?

Following is my code,

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(img_url).getContent());
imgvw.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

**Logcat**

```
03-23 14:59:17.696: I/System.out(386): Intent { cmp=com.example.png/.tab_cameraActivity }
03-23 14:59:17.696: I/System.out(386): LB 3
03-23 14:59:17.716: D/AndroidRuntime(386): Shutting down VM
03-23 14:59:17.716: W/dalvikvm(386): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.example.png/com.example.png.tab_cameraActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1577)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:130)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at  android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:342)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:680)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:349)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:149)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:556)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3100)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11644)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:481)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:281)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:249)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:69)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:304)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
 03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:76)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:153)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.example.png.tab_cameraActivity.getImagesDetails(tab_cameraActivity.java:73)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at   com.example.png.tab_cameraActivity.onCreate(tab_cameraActivity.java:57)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
 03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
03-23 14:59:17.736: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  ... 18 more
```

Comment: without code we same puzzle like you will you show ur code???

Comment: @HCD please visit my question again.

Comment: what does logcat shows you ?

Comment: can you post soem more relevant code?. Where do you execute the above code in asynctask?

Comment: can you provide logcat?

Comment: @Harshid sorry for delayed reply.here i got some power shutdown.\

Comment: @Harshid please visit my question again here i have included my logcat for regerence.

Comment: @HCD please visit my question again here i have included my logcat for regerence. – prabu just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting exception.

**NetworkOnMainThreadException:** The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

so you have to use **AsyncTask**.

Here is example of AsyncTask.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that you execute this code inside the UI Thread. This is prohibited in Android HoneyComb and above. You should consider using an AsyncTask or an Android Service to perform this request. Different options are available to help you with that. As a contributor of [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice), I believe this library would help.

Comment: I agree and this bugged me as well, but that's the most reasonable cause for such a problem without more logcat details.